# Can't render text with SDL2 using sdl2_ttf

Tags: c++

I always get `segmentation fault core dumpet error`. I have no idea what's wrong, I know that i don't free the stuff at the end but that's not the reason (I guess). I am trying to create a very simple application that renders any text that you put into it, I can't make it working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderTarget = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Init();

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("potato", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderTarget = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

        TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf",30);
        SDL_Color White = {255, 255, 255};
        SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "put your text here", White);
        SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderTarget, surfaceMessage);
        SDL_Rect Message_rect = {50,50,300,300};

    bool isRunning = true;
    SDL_Event ev;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
        {
            if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                isRunning = false;
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderTarget);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderTarget, Message, NULL, &Message_rect); //
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking if any `SDL` or `TTF` functions return null. An error could have occurred on any of those calls.